# Using a CTE to insert a parsed XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, common-table-expression

I'm developing a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure.

I want to parse this XML:

```
<Commissioning>
  <Item ProductionId="115100" ItemId="100" ItemPackagingLevelId="1" ItemFlag="0" TimeStamp="2014-04-28T16:02:59.913" Username="" Source="PLS" />
  <Item ProductionId="115101" ItemId="101" ItemPackagingLevelId="1" ItemFlag="0" TimeStamp="2014-04-28T16:03:00.113" Username="" Source="PLS" />
  <Item ProductionId="115102" ItemId="102" ItemPackagingLevelId="1" ItemFlag="0" TimeStamp="2014-04-28T16:03:00.317" Username="" Source="PLS" />
  <Item ProductionId="115103" ItemId="103" ItemPackagingLevelId="1" ItemFlag="0" TimeStamp="2014-04-28T16:03:00.517" Username="" Source="PLS" />
  <Item ProductionId="115104" ItemId="104" ItemPackagingLevelId="1" ItemFlag="0" TimeStamp="2014-04-28T16:03:00.727" Username="" Source="PLS" />
</Commissioning>
```

And insert `ItemId` and `ItemPackagingLevelId` in a CTE because I want to do some calculations with that data.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Thanks for this constructive downvote without saying why.

Comment: Sorry, I was the one that downvoted, I thought the tooltip ("This question doesn't show any research effort.") with my added comment explained why already. I think it would be good to show the code you've tried so far, tell us what the specific problems or obstacles were, etc. Currently your question reads as just a requirement with some sample data for which the requirement should be fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this...?

```
;with cte as (
    select 
        x.n.value('./@ItemId','varchar(100)') as ItemID,
        x.n.value('./@ItemPackagingLevelId','varchar(100)')  as LevelID
    from @x.nodes('/Commissioning/Item') x(n)
)
    select * from cte
```